# Is there a way to disable saving to checkpoints for Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working in an environment where writing to the disk space with a folder name like `.ipynb_checkpoints` is disallowed.

Unfortunately, this is Jupyter Notebook's default path for `Save and Checkpoint`.
Is there a way to configure Jupyter Notebook to not use the checkpoint feature or allow a different folder name?

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but perhaps close enough.

The path of the checkpoints folder is configurable so you could rename it to something allowed such as "_ipynb_checkpoints", or you could move it to a completely different folder.

You simply have to add

```
c.FileCheckpoints.checkpoint_dir = '_ipynb_checkpoints'
```

to *jupyter_notebook_config.py*

Comment: where is this config file usually found?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck Bit late, but this is in `~/.jupyter`, and you can run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to create the file. See https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Comment: Well, you are almost there!  Simply set `c.FileCheckpoints.checkpoint_dir = '' ` -  No folder is then created!

Comment: Well, I saw later that if the above action is taken, instead of a folder, NB creates a backup file in the path of the opened .ipynb  file, with the name '{filename}-checkpoint.ipynb'. I don't know how and if this can be prevented. But still, it is better than creating a whole folder!

Comment: Update for this solution using Jupyter Lab? I don't see `c.FileCheckpoints` in jupyter-notebook-config.py, and I'm not even sure that's the right config for Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 3):

You can uncheck `Settings -> AutosaveDocuments` to avoid autosave file,
but it always create `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder when you open a file, I can not find a solution to avoid this behavior,there is a way that you can specify a folder to collect all the checkpoint files and delete them together.

1. In jupyterlab, you can use `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to generate a config file named `jupyter_notebook_config.py` .
2. Then you can edit this file: `c.FileContentsManager.checkpoints_kwargs = {'root_dir': r'D:\'}` .

Or you can just use cammand line option

```
jupyter lab --FileContentsManager.checkpoints_kwargs="root_dir"="D:/"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30847603)

Comment: Thank you for this command line option, now the checkpoints are saved outside of the notebook folder and that works for me.

`jupyter lab --FileContentsManager.checkpoints_kwargs="root_dir"="/tmp"`

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to stop autosaves.

There is a contrib `nbextension` called `AutoSaveTime` if you have installed `jupyter-contrib-nbextensions` that adds an autosave time configuration on the toolbar of a notebook, just ensure:

```
"autosavetime/main": true
```

is set in your `notebook.json` configuration file.

Alternatively in a Cell, to change the autosave value for the current notebook, you can write:

```
%autosave 0
```

Or you can change your `custom.js` to make this permanent for all notebooks:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("notebook_loaded.Notebook",
            function () {
                IPython.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but the problem is not so much with the Autosave, but the face that when I click on "Save and Checkpoints" , or CTRL+S, Jupyter Notebook will try to create the .ipynb_checkpoints folder and save checkpoints there.
This is what's causing the error messages to occur because naming a folder with a preceeding . is prohibited in my environment.

I'm looking for a solution to just save and overwrite current file, but not create checkpoints at all.

Comment: Tried experimenting with save_hooks, but can't find a way to change the path of the checkpoints.
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue working on a sharepoint drive.