# renaming jupyter notebook checkpoint directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

Jupyter notebook automatically creates a hidden directory to store all checkpoint information - this was fine when I was working locally but I've recently started uploading my work to the cloud (namely OneDrive) and the hidden directory is causing some issues.

Is there a way to rename the checkpoint directory from `.ipynb_checkpoints` to something like `_ipynb_checkpoints` so it is not hidden.

I've found an answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865194/13562853, but I think this is outdated. I've searched the documentation with no luck.

Thank you